# Presenting separate linear regression models in one regression table?

Tags: r, regression, linear-model, r-squared

I've created this regression table, but I'm unsure if this is the correct way to present my results. The dependent variable is the proportion of each frame, and the independent variable is time (from 2012-2022), with the outcomes listed for all 11 frames analysed. These outcomes were all derived 11 separate simple linear regressions. I have R squared statistics for each of the 11 regressions, but I'm unsure how to calculate the R squared figure for this table, whether each result needs its own R squared figure given that they are all derived from separate regressions, or whether this is the wrong table for presenting these results. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: I cannot understand what this table is showing, because you describe exactly *two* variables -- "the dependent" and "the independent" variable -- so what do all these different quantities represent?  Perhaps the answer lies in understanding what you might mean by a "frame" and "analyzing" a frame, but clarification of what's going on here would be very helpful.